# Hissing sound coming from toliet

Tags: plumbing

last week I heard a kind of hissing sound coming from my toilet. I don't use that  toilet much so I just turned off the water from the bottom and the noise stopped. Well I really can't believe this but now my other toilet is hissing even louder. I don't see any leaking in the tank just noise coming from around the red cap on the toilet.

[I took a video and put it on youtube](https://youtu.be/MPcz3c3Me4A) so you could hear the sound.

I could really use some advise on this, I'm not feeling well these days and really don't need this added stress. I called a plumber and he said he would take care of both toilets for 220 but I really only want to spend that much if it's really necessary. Thanks in advance. .

Comment: why did you not include a link to the video?

Comment: turn the water back on, but only partially

Comment: i found the video ... i don't hear any abnormal hissing ... do you by chance wear a hearing aid?

Comment: no hearing aid, there is a hissing sound but it's hard to pick up on video I guess.

Comment: I didn't post the link because I didn't know if it was allowed on this website

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what a "red cap" is on a toilet, but if it's hissing then water is passing somewhere and the most likely is that the float-valve is letting through.

It might stop if you bounce it a couple of times, if some grit has got in the mechanism, but otherwise it's a new valve or washer/diaphragm depending on the type of valve.